# Does a superconductor have exactly zero resistance?

Tags: electrical-resistance, material-science, superconductivity

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20947/is-a-superconductor-really-a-super-conductor) already discusses the question but I did not understand the marked answer. It does not outright say whether a superconductor has zero resistance or not.

Do superconductors have exactly zero resistance, nearly zero resistance or does the concept of resistance as we know it break down when it comes to superconductors? Or is the question senseless because of experimental errors?

Comment: In its current form, this question is a duplicate of the one you linked. You should clarify what kind of answer you are looking for that sets this question apart from the other one.

Comment: @Chris I have edited. Is this good enough?

Comment: In the original answer it says: *Mathematical models predict...* From that statement it is not exactly clear if a) the model predicts *as a result* zero resistance or b) *assuming* zero resistance the model predicts finite to too-small-to-measure resistance when it comes to real world objects with finite sizes. Maybe the question is not a duplicate.